# Is it possible to convert a Layout to Image with the same size regardless of the phone's density?

Tags: android

I have an application that I need to convert a layout into an image but the problem is that the image will have a different resolution depending on the phone's density.

If I use the app on Phone A, the resolution will be 480x350, but on Phone B, the image's resolution will be 400x280. My question is: Is it possible to convert this layout into an image, but with the same resolution for every phone regardless on it's density?

My code:

```
    private void salva() {
    if(myDir.exists()==false) {
        myDir.mkdirs();
    }
    RL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.CardsLay);
    RL.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    img = RL.getDrawingCache();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(img);
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        canvas.drawBitmap(img, 0, 0, null);
        img.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        RL.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image saved on phone", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ops", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you get any solution for this problem ? If yes then please help me regarding this. any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I did not. I tried a few things like turning the layout orientation to horizontal before saving, saving the image, and then putting it back up, or putting the layout inside a ScrollView. They did help a little regarding the picture size, but they're not a real solution.